# How to display other component in one other *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have this table in html

```
<form [formGroup]="myform" (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
       <tbody>
              <tr class="group" *ngFor="let item of products;">
                <td>
                  <div>
                    {{item.product_type_id}}
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>{{item.product_id}}</td>
               </tr>
          </tbody>
    <form>
```

I have this products in ts code:     `this.products = this.ps.getProduct();` that getall my product.
Product have this property

```
export class Products {
    product_id: number;
    product_type_id: number;
    prodcttype: ProductType[];}
```

When I create a product, I get my productType from ws, like this

```
this.pts.getAllProductType().subscribe(
  producttype => {
    this.producttype = producttype;
  }
);
```

Product Type have this property

```
export class ProductType {
    product_type_name: string;
    description: number;
    default_price: number;
    product_type_id: string;}
```

I want to display in html  in this `{{item.product_type_id}}` -->   `{{item.product_type_name}}`

At the moment this doesn't function because product_type_name 
not found in Products

ts code:

```
    this.myform= new FormGroup({
      'invoice_number': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
      'invoice_date': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'client_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'products': this.fb.array([])    
    });

  ngOnInit() {

    this.products = this.ps.getProduct();
    console.log(this.products)

    this.pts.getAllProductType().subscribe(
      producttype => {
        this.producttype = producttype;
      }
    );
  submit() {}
}
```

service producttype

```
  public getAllProductType(): Observable<ProductType[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.getAllProductType), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(producttype => {
            return new ProductType(producttype);
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

service product

```
  private products: Products[] = [];
  getProduct() {
    return this.products;
  }
```

Can you suggest me any solution, how to solve it?

Comment: It would be great help if you can make stackblitz project of this

Comment: You want to print `{{item.product_type_name}}` but your item is having array of `productTypes` in `prodcttype: ProductType[]`. So is there any gap in information shared or you want to print all the `product_type_names` in the array ?

Comment: The joint is product_type_id, so in the list are 4 product types, each of which has product_type_id and product_type_name. The product has only producty_type_id to producttype.

Comment: Ok so means in `products` its `prodcttype: ProductType` not array. You want to print the `product_type_name` of that `producttype`? Still not able to understand your question or issue you are facing.

Comment: I have a form sale, in this form i have some data from sale and the products we want to sell, this form I display in a table (like in post) my product, in this product I have product type, ex, Computer, this product have product_type_id: 123456. Now, In my table, i display only 123456, but I want to display Computer.  Computer, 123456 are  in ProductType, and only 123456 is in Product. My problem is, how to display Computer in this table?

Comment: Let me know if it works by accepting and  upvoting ans :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the detail question in the comments I would suggest you to make a new function in the component which would filter `productType` and provide you with `productName`. Code for same is as follow:

Add following function in componnent

```
getProductName(productTypeId: string) {
    const [filteredProdType] = this.producttype.filter(pt => pt.product_type_id== productTypeId);
    return filteredProdType.product_type_name;
}
```

And change your template to

```
<form [formGroup]="myform" (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
   <tbody>
          <tr class="group" *ngFor="let item of products;">
            <td>
              <div>
                {{item.product_type_id}}
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{getProductName(item.product_type_id)}}</td>
           </tr>
      </tbody>
<form>
```

this will fetch the product name of `item` by using `product_type_id`.

Hope this help. Add comments if further help needed.

Comment: Work perfect! Thank you so much :)

Comment: And other question if you can. In this situation, If I want to use and other product. How to edit this function. For example getProductName(productTypeId: string) {
    const [filteredProdType] = this.producttype.filter(pt => pt.product_type_id== productTypeId);
    return filteredProdType.product_type_name;
      const [filteredProd] = this.contrat.filter(pt => pt.contrat_id === productTypeId);
      return filteredProd.contratdesc;}

Comment: the code seems fine. If it still doesnt work you can post more details or a seprate question. I will surely ans :)

Comment: Thank you. This is my post for this question. Look please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295200/how-to-display-complicate-component-in-one-ngfor